# i cant remove underline

Tags: html, css, styles, underline

bold-normal,italic-normal working but underline-none not working? why?How fix first example with change styles parameters.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
vurgulu {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size:40;
}
vurgusuz{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size:40;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
Why output different? why first ex. zalimi underline?<br>
<vurgulu>Zulmü alkışlayamam, <vurgusuz>zalimi</vurgusuz> asla sevemem;</vurgulu>
<br>
<vurgulu>Zulmü alkışlayamam, </vurgulu><vurgusuz>zalimi</vurgusuz><vurgulu> asla sevemem;</vurgulu> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `vurgusuz` to `display: inline-block`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    vurgulu {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 40;
    }
    vurgusuz {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 40;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Why output different? why first ex. zalimi underline?
  <br>
  <vurgulu>Zulmü alkışlayamam,
    <vurgusuz>zalimi</vurgusuz>asla sevemem;</vurgulu>
  <br>
  <vurgulu>Zulmü alkışlayamam,</vurgulu>
  <vurgusuz>zalimi</vurgusuz>
  <vurgulu>asla sevemem;</vurgulu>
</body>

</html>
```